# zsh autocompletion appears to only work with built in commands

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm new to zsh, just switched over from fish. I'm trying to get autocomplete working so it displays argument/flag options for commands upon pressing tab.

Currently this works, but it only appears to work for built in commands. For example, it works for ls, grep, git, etc. but does not work for programs I have added myself. For example, fd-find, exa, and nvm all do not work.

For nvm, I have enabled the nvm plugin using Oh My Zsh. I know the plugin is working in general, because nvm itself is working (and it wasn't before enabling the plugin).

For fd-find, I see the auto-completion file in `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_fd`

For exa, I manually downloaded and placed the autocompletion file in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_exa` as instructed by the site.

All 3 of these programs do not show me the typical arguments/flags autocomplete menu the way built in commands do. I'm not sure what is wrong.

I echoed the fpath environment variable to make sure `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` was in there. It is, along with `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/`

When I run `which nvm`, I get:

```
_nvm () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
```

Which is actually what I get for all of _nvm, _exa, _fd.

Not sure what else to try.

Any suggestions for how to get autocomplete working properly?

Other info: I'm on a System76 Darter Pro laptop running Pop!_OS.

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix that worked for me. After searching through zsh issues related to autocomplete on github, [this solution](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5651#issuecomment-417984071) worked for me. Credit was given to the [original source of the solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210930/completions-stopped-working-after-upgrading-zsh/210931#210931) on stackexchange.

The solution was simply to remove all zcompdump files:

```
rm ~/.zcompdump*
```

After running the above command, autocomplete works and expands out the possible flags/arguments for non-builtin programs!

Comment: This is the answer.